# Importing users from one database to another and saving passwords

Tags: database, profiles

I have been trying to formulate a way to take a database SQL file of users from one database and add it to another WordPress database while saving the old WordPress site passwords on the new WordPress install. 
I know that the salts need to be the same for it to work, and I know that the `wp_usermeta` and `wp_user` are the tables i need to import.

I just need to know if it do this will people still need to change their passwords?

Comment: I can do a migration and it keeps all the users and pass, there must be a way. Does the site you are migrating too need to stay in-tact and you are just adding the users?

Comment: yes, it should remain the same and i just need to add the users.

Comment: Does anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: Migrating WordPress users with their password is easily possible with this free [WordPress user import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com).

Answer (score 0):

At first, I think you should sync your database tables via linux `rsync` command. It is a solid way, more as an script inside your wp install and his dependencies.

However you will update the password in the second table after an change of a password. I think you should use the WP hook after the change and fire on this hook an copy of the password. The hook is

```
/**
  * Fires after the user's password is reset.
  *
  * @since 4.4.0
  *
  * @param object $user     The user.
  * @param string $new_pass New user password.
  */
  do_action( 'after_password_reset', $user, $new_pass );
```

However you can also use the hook after a change of the profile, that include the change of the password - Hook `profile_update`.

```
/**
 * Fires immediately after an existing user is updated.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param int     $user_id       User ID.
 * @param WP_User $old_user_data Object containing user's data prior to update.
 */
do_action( 'profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data );
```